# Can I configure Fluent NHibernate to move all child entities of deleted parent to new parent?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I need something like "AllDeleteOrphan" but instead of deletion it must change parent of all orphan entities to a special entity that represent "not specified" state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there are any built in functionality that supports this.

What you could probably do is create an interceptor and add custom logic into the OnDelete method to do what you need.

Some articles that touches on your point:

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2013/03/21/soft-deletes-with-nhibernate.aspx
http://candland.net/2010/01/09/intercepting-nhibernate-to-handle-additional-database-work/